# THREE.js how to make transparent front walls in 3d room model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to make a 3d room in three.js. I want the walls, that are in front of the camera view, to become transparent as I rotate the room.

Here is example what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/tp2f2oo4/

It seems that solution is adding THREE.BackSide to the material.

```
var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff, 
    transparent: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
} );
```

Indeed this works perfectly when a room acts as a single THREE.BoxGeometry,
but in my case, every wall, ceiling, and floor are separate THREE.BoxGeometry objects. Is there any way to hide them or not rendering when are in front of the camera view?

Answer (score 6):

You want to hide a mesh based on some condition. This is a perfect use case for using the `onBeforeRender()` and `onAfterRender()` methods.

```
// callbacks
var onBeforeRender = function() {

    var v = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function onBeforeRender( renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group ) {

        // this is one way. adapt to your use case.
        if ( v.subVectors( camera.position, this.position ).dot( this.userData.normal ) < 0 ) {

            geometry.setDrawRange( 0, 0 ); // it is too late to set visible = false, so do this, instead

        }

    };

}();

var onAfterRender = function( renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group ) {

    geometry.setDrawRange( 0, Infinity );

};

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );
mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( mesh );
mesh.userData.normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 );
mesh.onBeforeRender = onBeforeRender;
mesh.onAfterRender = onAfterRender;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qh815xa/

three.js r.114

Comment: Hi @WestLangley I've been struggling to get this working with different position of walls (x and z offset by +20, y by +8). I understand that what you've done above is a simpler use case. Would greatly appreciate if you can help me with the math for handling it for walls in other x, y and z position. 
Fiddle with updated geometry positions http://jsfiddle.net/g4aqbzeL/4/

Comment: @noobMama I changed the algorithm so it is more intuitive. Your use case: http://jsfiddle.net/h8ag9u6z/

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps me conceptualize this soo much better :)

Comment: One quick follow up. Now that the wall is hidden using drawRange property, is there an effective way to use raycaster to pick Objects behind the wall (only if wall is invisible) ?
By default the raycaster seems to only filter out objects that have visible=false. But we don't have that luxury here.

Comment: @noobMama If you need help, it is best if you post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ray-casting to determine which walls to turn off. Basically, shoot a ray from your camera, and set the transparency of the wall it intersects.

For a simplified case, see `updateWallTransparency_simple` in the snippet below. It fires a ray from the center of the camera, and sets the transparency of the intersected wall.

However, you'll probably encounter a literal corner case, where you transition from one wall into the next. You can compensate for this with a second raycast, but you need to offset the two rays from the center, so they won't intersect the same wall in the case of a corner. See `updateWallTransparency_corners` in the snippet below for an example.

Now this is a highly simplified case. If your wall shapes are more complex, you'll need to perform further checks to see if certain walls should be hidden or not. Also, if you tip the camera too far up, you'll notice it will make the back walls hidden instead. There is a lot more to consider for this problem as a whole, but this should get you started.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  FOV = 35,
  NEAR = 1,
  FAR = 1000,
  degrad = (Math.PI / 180),
  walls = [];

var raycaster = null,
  coords = null;

function updateWallTransparency_simple() {
  // reset all walls. You can optimize this by storing which ones are transparent/not
  walls.forEach(function(wall) {
    wall.material.opacity = 1;
  });

  raycaster.setFromCamera(coords, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(walls);
  if (intersects && intersects.length > 0) {
    intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.25;
  }
}

function updateWallTransparency_corners() {
  // reset all walls. You can optimize this by storing which ones are transparent/not
  walls.forEach(function(wall) {
    wall.material.opacity = 1;
  });

  coords.set(-0.1, 0);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(coords, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(walls);
  if (intersects && intersects.length > 0) {
    intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.25;
  }

  coords.set(0.1, 0);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(coords, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(walls);
  if (intersects && intersects.length > 0) {
    intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.25;
  }
}

function populateScene() {
  var geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 0.1),
    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "darkred",
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 1
    });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  mesh.position.set(0, 0, -10);
  mesh.name = "backWall";
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  walls.push(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat.clone());
  mesh.name = "frontWall";
  mesh.position.set(0, 0, 10);
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  walls.push(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat.clone());
  mesh.name = "leftWall";
  mesh.position.set(-10, 0, 0);
  mesh.rotation.set(0, (Math.PI / 180) * 90, 0);
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  walls.push(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat.clone());
  mesh.name = "rightWall";
  mesh.position.set(10, 0, 0);
  mesh.rotation.set(0, (Math.PI / 180) * 90, 0);
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  walls.push(mesh);

  geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(50, 0.1, 50),
    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "green"
    });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  mesh.position.set(0, -10, 0);
  mesh.name = "ground";
  scene.add(mesh);

  geo = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry(2, 0.5, 100, 16),
    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "blue"
    });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  mesh.name = "insideObject";
  scene.add(mesh);
}

function init() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue";

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.padding = "0";

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.position.z = 50;
  scene.add(camera);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.enableZoom = false;
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera.add(light);

  light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x00ff00, 1);
  scene.add(light);

  stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

  resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

  populateScene();

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  coords = new THREE.Vector3();

  animate();
}

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  if (renderer && camera && controls) {
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  //updateWallTransparency_simple();
  updateWallTransparency_corners();
  render();
  stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
  init();
}

(function() {
  function addScript(url, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.addEventListener("load", callback);
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function() {
    addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js", function() {
      addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function() {
        threeReady();
      })
    })
  })
})();
```